# How to validate fields using jquery in asp.net mvc 3 razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

here my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RegisterForm" }))      
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, 
                      new { size = "40", 
                            @onchange = "UserNameVal();", 
                            @tabindex = "1" })
}

$("#RegisterForm").validate({

        rules: {
            EmailAddress: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            EmailAddress: {
                required: "<br/> Please enter the Email address"
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use annotation to validate the fields? it's much easier and cleaner, you can do as below:

```
 public class MyModel
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Email address")]
     public string Email { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: I am glade that this helped you.

Comment: i tried using jquery..but it didn't work out... i always prefer jquery for validation...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#RegisterForm").valid()) {
    $("#RegisterForm").submit();
}
```